# TFS 2013 Team Build - Queued Build Remains in In Progress Status

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, ms-release-management

I'm in the process of getting Release Management setup.  I have the release management server configured along with the controllers, agents, release template, and deployment agents.  When I attempt to create a New Release from the release template upon trying to specify the Build I get the error "There is no available build for the selected build definition".

When I attempt to build using Team Build the status of the queued build remains in In Progress status. Not sure how to troubleshoot this for there is no information provided in the Build Explorer. I've tied using the Default Template and the Release Default Template for the build definition.

This is for Visual Studio on prem.  TFS version 2013.

Comment: **Do not** invest in release management server. It is deprecated and there is no upgrade path to modern solutions. You would be far better served by investing the time into upgrading TFS to a modern version, which has a far better, more robust release pipeline solution. Remember, TFS 2013 is almost 7 years old and there have been at least 4 **major** releases since then, with hundreds of new features.

Comment: Are other builds working? Is this the first build you are trying? Make sure that the tfsjobagent service is running.  Not sure if it was called this in 2013, I haven't run this version of tfs in 6 years.  Good luck.